# Example of random variables and deterministic constants

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ and a sequence of deterministic constants $(a_n)$ such that:

1. $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. satisfying $E(X_1) = 0$ and $|X_n(\omega)| \leq 1$, $\forall \omega$, $\forall n$
2. $(a_n)$ satisfies $0 < m \leq a_n \leq M$, $\forall n$
3. $|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i| > M |\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|$ a.s. for $n$ large.

It is possible to get such $(X_n)$ and $(a_n)$? Thanks.

Comment: where does the question from?

Comment: it does not came from a book...

Comment: Then what inspired the question? I had a go at trying to construct counter examples and got nowhere.